# Decomposing timeseries of a trended sinusoid with noise

Tags: r, time-series, decomposition

I am trying to learn the basic timeseries functions in R and am struggling to decompose a simple sinusoid with period 100 time units that I added a linear trended and random normal noise to.  I am not sure what to set the frequency to when I create the timeseries object.

By usual math & physics definitions the period is 100 and freq=1/100 but when I do this it does not recreate the sinusoid (looks wrong when I plot it).  Setting the frequency=1 creates the plot correctly but then decompose gives an error message saying there are "not two periods in the data."  What am I doing wrong?  Here's the code I am trying:

```
# create sinusoid with period of 100
sinusoid.period100 <- sin((2*pi/100)*(seq(0, 500, 1)))

# create linear trend to add to sinusoid
lin.trend.501 <- seq(0, 1, length.out=501)

# create noise to add to sinusoid
noise.normal.501 <- rnorm(501, 0, 0.1)

# add sinusoid, linear trend and noise together

sinusoid.noisyAndtrended.period100 <- sinusoid.period100 + 
               lin.trend.501 + noise.normal.501

# convert to a timeseries object
sinusoid.noisyAndtrended.period100.ts <- 
   ts(sinusoid.noisyAndtrended.period100, 0, 500, deltat=1, 
        frequency=1)

# attempting to decompose timeseries back into sinusoid, 
# linear trend and noise

decompose(sinusoid.noisyAndtrended.period100.ts)
```